# app with WorkManager work better on android API 27 than API 28

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, background-process, android-workmanager

The same application that uses workManager and displays local notifications about every full hour works better on API 27 than on API 28.

On my API 27 android phone I receive a notification with a maximum delay of 15 minutes. Even when i have a low battery.

But on the Android phone with API 28 it sometimes happens that I receive a notification with over an hour delay.

For example, in my worker I set the notification to come at 13:00:00 and in API 27 I get it at 13:05:34. And that's ok. While in API 28 I receive notification at 14:43:06.

Why does the same application work differently? What does API 28 have?